# How do I get a random field from password?

Tags: php, ruby, algorithm

I have seen log-in pages where the page asks for a random field from your password. For example, enter the second, fifth and first character from your password. And if you refresh the page it will ask for some other random fields.

I have two questions about this:

1. How do I fetch the length before the user POSTs the password and not ask for fields that do not exist? For example, the password length is a four digit number and the app won't ask for the fifth character.
2. Is it a good idea to transform the password stored in the database to an array and then check for certain fields in the array? For example, `Third character == password[2]`.

A PHP or Ruby sample implementation will be more than useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text! And if you're using any sites with the policy you are describing, email them and tell them it's horrible practice, then avoid them at all cost!

Comment: i have not seen any log in page like this. maybe an example would be nice

Comment: 1- you need to get the password length from DB using simple query `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(password) from table where condition`

Comment: On top of the fact that it encourages insecure password storage, this technique really offers nothing more than just entering your password normally.

Comment: @JimL yes i know that, i was curious about the implementation of all this.

Comment: A site on my work's intranet does this but with a 8 digit pin number. It drives me crazy not to mention signalling that it is stored in plain text somewhere. How is entering part of a pin number more secure than entering the whole pin number? But I digress. Just saying that, yes, I have seen this done and, no, do not ever do this yourself.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that you show code showing you've attempted to solve the problem. Please show us your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious if this validation is being done on the actual password that is being stored in plain text in a database (which would be bad), or if this validation is simply trying to avert bruteforce attacks by having the user validate the password they just entered.  Kind of like a captcha.  If the later is the case, maybe you could implement something in javascript.  Here is a fiddle of something like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/fTPJy/1/

```
$apparently = 'I have to post code to link to a jsfiddle';
```